# Should "Proof Assistants for Vim Users" be made community wiki?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, specific-question, community-wiki

A while ago I asked [a question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/101/proof-assistants-for-vim-users) about information regarding vim support for various proof assistants.

As I've had answers come in, I've started wondering if we should make it community wiki, since I would love to get answers with perspectives on lots of proof assistants, and ideally for the information to be updated as years go by and (neo)vim support improves.
All in all, it seems like a perfect candidate for CW.

That said, since this is a new SE, I figured I would double check here to make sure that other people agree.

If other people also feel like it should be CW'd, and someone with the power to do so sees this, then I would love for it to be updated ^_^.

Answer (score 7):

My advise might be different than many others but that is why you asked.

While I personally like making some questions a wiki for the same reasons you note, since this site is so new, many users are having to earn reputation to unlock privileges and if a question is made a wiki they will no longer earn points for their effort. While some will not care, some will. So it is a double edged sword.

If it were my question I would just hold off for a year or so to allow others to join the site and get their input. My thinking is that with the start of each new university semester this site should see an influx of new users. I would also announce a date on which the question will be converted into a wiki. Again this is just my view so feel free to disagree and/or ignore.

---

Another option that I often do myself is to put such information into the wiki tag. Most people don't think of tags as a wiki page but they should. Check the [privileges](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and you will not see *approve tag edits*, but *approve tag wiki edits*.

If you take this route then everyone should be able to edit the info, each edit will still need two approvals to go live. The nice thing about doing it this way is every question with the tag has all of the info just a click away.

Comment: https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/tags-are-for-more-than-just-questions is a 404...